# Fluent NHib causing visual studio 2010 hanging at runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fluent-nhibernate, crash

Just installed and migrated a 2008 solution on Vista ultimate 64 and .net 4.0. Everything builds and tests run surprisingly well but I got the hang description below while trying to run the app under SQLite.

It turns out that the hang has got something to do when the call is made for FNH to build the session factory during a run, the only feedback I get is that the database wasn't configure properly without any inner exception. The strange part is that the exact code works perfectly under tests.

Any clues?

```
FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException was unhandled
Message: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

* Database was not configured through Database method.
```

> Description:   A problem caused this
>   program to stop interacting with
>   Windows.
>
> Problem signature:     Problem Event
>   Name: AppHangB1     Application
>   Name: devenv.exe     Application
>   Version:  10.0.30319.1     Application
>   Timestamp:    4ba1fab3     Hang
>   Signature:    b9ed     Hang Type: 6152
>   OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.256.1
>   Locale ID:    1033     Additional Hang
>   Signature
>   1:    005de38e6b4bb3afd8e147932c6431cc
>   Additional Hang Signature 2:  d54c
>   Additional Hang Signature
>   3:    05f671c8289bf8dd31e6ccfe265baa77
>   Additional Hang Signature 4:  784c
>   Additional Hang Signature
>   5:    c8207f54dadf3eb38dfcf1ae152f4229
>   Additional Hang Signature 6:  ff83
>   Additional Hang Signature
>   7:    220932152f3f04fffb6ca3abf15e6dc6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a SQLite issue, not FNH; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649194/sqlite-nhibernate-configuration-with-net-4-0-and-vs-2010)