# FileLoadException in vs 2010 xaml designer with SLite 1.0.66

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite, configuration, xaml-designer

This is in part a continuation of issues encountered in configuring SQLite in a vs 2010 .Net 4.0 environment, originally started in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649194/sqlite-nhibernate-configuration-with-net-4-0-and-vs-2010).

The focus of that post was getting both unit testing and application runtime working, which has been resolved and so marked as answered accordingly. The focus of this post is the exception thrown in the XAML editor detailed below.

I have enabled the loadFromRemoteSources switch, which fixed my runtime issue, but not the editor exception.

Cheers,
Berryl

```
System.IO.FileLoadException
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.RemoteReferenceProxy.VsReflectionResolver.GetRuntimeAssembly(Assembly reflectionAssembly)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.ReflectionMetadataContext.CachingReflectionResolver.GetRuntimeAssembly(Assembly reflectionAssembly)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.ReflectionMetadataContext.Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.IReflectionResolver.GetRuntimeAssembly(Assembly reflectionAssembly)
at MS.Internal.Metadata.ClrAssembly.GetRuntimeMetadata(Object reflectionMetadata)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.AttributeTableContainer.<MergeAttributesIterator>d__c.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.AttributeTableContainer.GetAttributes(Assembly assembly, Type attributeType, Func`2 reflectionMapper)
at MS.Internal.Metadata.ClrAssembly.GetAttributes(ITypeMetadata attributeType)
at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlAssembly.get_XmlNamespaceCompatibilityMappings()
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlExtensionImplementations.GetXmlNamespaceCompatibilityMappings(IAssemblyMetadata sourceAssembly)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlExtensions.GetXmlNamespaceCompatibilityMappings(IAssemblyMetadata source)
at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.BuildSubsumption()
at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.SubsumingNamespace(Identifier identifier)
at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.BuildScope(PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context)
at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.ConvertToXaml(XamlElement parent, PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context, IMarkupSourceProvider provider)
at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.FullParse(Boolean convertToXamlWithErrors)
at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.get_RootItem()
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.Trees.ModifiableDocumentTree.get_ModifiableRootItem()
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.MarkupDocumentManagerBase.get_LoadState()
at MS.Internal.Host.PersistenceSubsystem.Load()
at MS.Internal.Host.Designer.Load()
at MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.Load()
at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedView.Load()
at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedDesignerFactory.Load(IsolatedView view)
at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.Load()
at MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView()


System.NotSupportedException
An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem - looking for fixes now. sqlite is certainly a pain to get working in .NET 4. I have my suspicions that XAML editor is looking for a 32bit assembly. At the very top of my exception it says "System.BadImageFormatException".

Comment: I am using VS2010 with Sqlite 1.0.66 as you and I have no problem with it. Thats my app.config:<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the party with this response, but having spent most of the morning with the same issue (albeit with a different DLL to the OP), I can provide a solution for anyone else unfortunate enough to come across this puzzling problem.

The error message suggests that you are trying to load an assembly from a network location or the web - a bit misleading, but also kind of true.

The issue is caused by Windows 7 "knowing" that the DLL has been downloaded from the web, even though it might have been inside a zip file at the time. The file is therefore marked as being potentially unsafe. To resolve it, right-click the DLL, choose Properties, then click the "Unblock" button. Voila! (Alternatively you could unblock the zip file prior to extracting the files within).

Comment: I *think* now that we can get the dll via Nuget it becomes a non-issue as well, but yeah, as fresh as this can be 2 years after the party your answer makes sense. Cheers